# How is this system a reversable system if it defies the definition?

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

From Strogatz's Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos:

> A reversible system is any second-order system
>   that is invariant under $t \rightarrow -t$ and $y \rightarrow -y$.  For example, any system of the form
>
> $x ' = f(x,y)$
>
> $y' = g(x,y)$
>
> where $f$ is odd in $y$ and $g$ is even in $y$ (i.e., $f(x,-y) = - f(x, y)$ and
>   $g(x, -y) = g(x, y) )$ is reversible.

Strogatz claims that the system $x' = 2 \cos x - \cos y, y' = 2 \cos y - \cos x$ should be a reversible system, but it fails to satisfy the definition as $2 \cos x - \cos (-y) \neq -[2 \cos x - \cos y]$.

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 2):

That example (Ex. 6.6.3) illustrates a more general definition of reversibility, stated immediately above it on the same page, which involves specifying an involution $R(\mathbf{x})$.

In Ex. 6.6.3 he's using $R(x,y)=(-x,-y)$.

In the previous examples (and in the first definition that you have quoted)
it was $R(x,y)=(x,-y)$.

Comment: But shouldn't the definitions both be true for this?

Comment: @OliverG The "definition" in the beginning of your question isn't really a definition of reversible system: it's just one of the examples. The real definition is when there is an involution $R$ (i.e., map such that $R \circ R = {\rm id}$) that conjugates flow $\varphi^t$ with its inverse: $R \circ \varphi^t = \varphi^{-t} \circ R$.

Comment: Even if it's just one of the examples shouldn't the definition still apply?  It's a system of the form $x ' = f(x,y), y ' = g(x,y)$, so if it's being claimed as reversible then doesn't it have to satisfy the conditions in the above box?

Comment: @OliverG: The system is reversible in the *wider* sense that he just defined (where you are free to choose a different map $R$), *not* in the *narrower* sense of the earlier definition that you're referring to (with a specific choice of $R$). That first definition was just a preliminary one, to warm up for the real definition.

Comment: Thanks, @HansLundmark, that's exactly what I've meant :)